# Unable to transfer amount to bank account of user in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to transfer money to user bank account.

I have created **"managed account"** for that user and in that manage account there are multiple bank accounts. So How do I transfer money from stripe balance to users bank account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.First transfer money to Managed Account.

2.Set key of managed account of bank account in which you need to transfer amount using following,

`stripe.setApiKey("Set secret key of managed account");`

3.Then transfer money to bank account using bank account id.

```
stripe.transfers.create({
       amount: "amount to be transferred",
       currency: "usd",
       destination: "Bank account id",
       statement_descriptor: "Transfer from Managed Account Stripe balance to Managed Account Bank Account"
                    })
```

Comment: how a real bank account of a customer who is not stripe member, will enter his account details?

Comment: You are using this functionality in your application or what? Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: In my application. Managed Accounts not available in AUstralia so only way to do is to ask user to get registered with Stipe and then make transaction to their account via API. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By default a managed account will have automatic transfers enabled. This means that every day Stripe will go through, see if an account has available funds and if so create a transfer for that user to their bank account.

If you have disabled automatic transfers for an account, they would be on manual transfers, where the transfers have to be manually created via the api for that account

For instance the code below would transfer $10 to the connected account's bank account from their available balance.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
   -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
   -H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}" \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d recipient=self
```

I'd also recommend reading Stripe's API documentation on this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-transfers